# Let $\left| {{a_{ii}}} \right| > \sum\limits_{i \ne j} {\left| {{a_{ij}}} \right|} $.Why does $A$ is nonsingular? .

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in {M_n}$ and $\left| {{a_{ii}}} \right| > \sum\limits_{j \ne i} {\left| {{a_{ij}}} \right|} $.Why does $A$ is nonsingular?

Comment: You should write $j \ne i$, not $i \ne j$, since you're summing over $j$.

Comment: Dear @Kavir I see that, although you have already asked 5 question in this site and received answers in most of them, you have not mark a best answer in any of them. You can do it so by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer that you think is the one that helped you the most. Please [read here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Let $X = (x_j)$ be a nonzero column matrix. Prove that $AX \ne 0$ by considering the index $s$ for which $x_s$ has the largest absolute value.